# Using defaults with app.add_url_rule in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am setting a url endpoint with the following:

**manager.py**

```
from xxx import ContactAPI
from xxx.models import Contact

# self.app is my Flask app
# self.session is SQLAlchemy Session

api_name = 'contact'
instance_endpoint = '/%s/<int:instid>' % api_name
methods = ['GET']

api_view = ContactAPI.as_view(api_name, self.session,
                              Contact, app)

self.app.add_url_rule(instance_endpoint, methods=methods, 
                      defaults={'instid': None},
                      view_func=api_view)
```

And overriding `get()` in my ContactAPI class:

**views.py**

```
from flask.views import MethodView

class ContactAPI(MethodView):

    def __init__(self, session, model, app, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactAPI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, instid):
        print instid
```

When I hit the URL `/contact/1` I get `instid` printed as `None`.

When I remove the `defaults={'instid': None},` line from manager.py, I get `instid` printed as 1.

Why is having the defaults line in my call to `add_url_rule` overriding what I'm putting in my URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I need to register two endpoints when using `defaults`.

Because `{'instid': None}` is passed into `get()` in my ContactAPI view as a kwarg, I need to tell Flask to set `instid` to None when the URL `/contact` is hit.

When I hit `/contact/1`, I need to use `<int:instid>`.  To do this, I need to remove the `defaults` kwarg in my call to `add_url_rule()`.

**manager.py**

```
from xxx import ContactAPI
from xxx.models import Contact

# self.app is my Flask app
# self.session is SQLAlchemy Session

api_name = 'contact'
instance_endpoint = '/%s/<int:instid>' % api_name
collection_endpoint = '/%s' % api_name

methods = ['GET']

api_view = ContactAPI.as_view(api_name, self.session,
                              Contact, app)

self.app.add_url_rule(instance_endpoint, methods=methods, 
                      view_func=api_view)

self.app.add_url_rule(collection_endpoint, methods=methods, 
                      defaults={'instid': None},
                      view_func=api_view)
```

Relevant Werkzeug docs: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule

Thanks to `asdf` in the #flask IRC channel for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

A complete example of a similar thing is there in the flask docs - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/views/